# Upgrade to pulseaudio 13.0+ on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: upgrade, pulseaudio

Is it possible to upgrade Pulseaudio to [v13.0](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/1:13.0-1ubuntu1.1) or higher on Ubuntu 18.04?  If so, how?

Comment: In theory, it's' possible. However, it's completely untested: It might break your system quite badly. Advice: It's generally a bad idea. For newer versions of software, it's wiser to use a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion